# How can I measure the overall error in the edges of a triangular mesh?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I look at a number of pointlike objects on a 2D plane and measure the straight line distances between them. For example:

[image]

These measurements contain individual errors. How can I measure the overall error in the mesh?

I could do this with physical simulation, by placing vertices at first-estimate coordinates and having the edges be springs, then let it settle iteratively to a minimum-energy configuration. I could then conclude that this configuration is "true" and compare the initial and final edge lengths.

That's one option, but it has a number of issues. I am wondering if, **given some chosen error function**, there is another, more analytical way to measure the overall error in such a mesh?

(I guess I'm asking if we can conclude whether or not the proposed measurements plausibly fit *some* true model, to some tolerance.)

Comment: There is no "one correct way" of defining the overall error. You will need to choose an error function that emphasizes what is most important to your application. The sum of the absolute values of the errors, or the sum of the squares of the errors, are the two most common choices.

Comment: Maybe looking at the applications listed on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_geometry might be useful, to see what metrics these use. [Cayley-Menger determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant) initially came to my mind to decide or measure flatness, but by themselves that only applies to 4 points in the plane, not arbitrary number, so you'd still need to combine these determinant values somehow.